# Am I using clearInterval incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I am making a stopwatch program with JavaScript and I want it to start and stop when you press the spacebar. When I press the spacebar once, the timer starts. The second time I press the spacebar, it restarts and immediately starts counting again.

```
document.body.onkeypress = function(key) {
    if (key.keyCode == 32) {
        if (inSession) {
            inSession = false;  
            timer = 0;
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timer;
            clearInterval(incrementTimer);
        } else {
            inSession = true;
            var incrementTimer = setInterval(increment, 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

^ Here is my event function. How do I change my program to make the stopwatch completely stop when you click the spacebar the second time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `var incrementTimer` to be declared outside of the function, right now it gets [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the top and will be undefined every time `onkeypress` is called.

```js
var incrementTimer;
document.body.onkeypress = function(key) {
    if (key.keyCode == 32) {
        if (inSession) {
            inSession = false;  
            timer = 0;
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timer;
            clearInterval(incrementTimer);
        } else {
            inSession = true;
            incrementTimer = setInterval(increment, 1000)
        }
    }
}
```